# Community edition of Visual Studio 2017 interferes with Drivers

Tags: visual-studio

I installed the community edition of Visual Studio 2017, and 
the installation went pretty smooth.

However, after reboot I had the following problems.
Somehow the drivers of Visual Studio 2017 interfered with the connectivity of my existing drivers. I am
1. No longer able to launch apps using the Microsoft app launcher console
2. Connectivity to 95% of websites gone.
3. Wireless driver to HP-printer is not working.

Google, Yahoo, Facebook, in general big websites are reachable.
95% of other websites, smaller websites give me a DNS error.

I uninstalled the "Community edition of Visual Studio 2017", and everything is back to normal.
I need Visual Studio 2017 for the CUDA drivers used by my GPU.

Acer Aspire V15 Nitro-Black Edition 
NVidia GeForce GTX 960M GPU

Any advice or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I would not have expected this.  which workflows did you install?  did you report this on connect?

Comment: "Drivers of Visual Studio 2017", Visual Studio 2017 doesn't install any *drivers*. If, however, the applications that were broken when VS2017 was installed relies on dll's that VS2017 replaces then that is a problem with those other applications but to be honest, I find this doubtful. Have you tried installing VS2017 once again and seeing if this problem occurs once more?